# why isn't this JPA query returning a list of my specific class?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a JPA object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="WF_GROUP")
public class Group {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  private String groupName;
  private long parentId;

/* ... */

}
```

I have a GroupDAO with this method:

```
public List<Group> getAllGroups() {
  List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
  String query = "select * from WF_GROUP";
  Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query);
  groups.addAll( q.getResultList() );
  return groups;
}
```

The problem is the q.getResultList() returns a result list of type Object than contains an object array for each property.

Why doesn't q.getResultList() return a list of Group objects?

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't specify which class the native query should return. Have a look at the other [createNativeQuery](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_sqlquery.html) methods, taking additional arguments.

Note that the point of using JPA is to use objects rather than database tables. JPQL is there for that. You should use the following code:

```
String query = "select group from Group group"; // this is JPQL
TypedQuery<Group> q = getEntityManager().createQuery(query, Group.class);
groups.addAll(q.getResultList());
```